# How can I create if statements in pandas to export to xlsx file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I want to create an if statement using pandas headers in which it will iterate through each row of the four rows which has the data to check the following conditions:
data should exist in the following columns in each row to be stored in worksheet 1 xlsx or it will be stored in worksheet 2
1) First name 2) Last Name 3) whether it is an "Individual" or Company contact, if
Company Title should exist, 4) the contact must have at least have one Work or Personal info that include one phone
or address or email.

I have tried the df.loc method but I do not know where to put the action statement

```
import csv
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
#I inserted file location 
with open(r'filelocation\file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    newlist= list(spamreader)

df = pd.DataFrame(newlist[1:], columns=newlist[0])
addresses = df.address_1.tolist()
df = df[['Lastname', 'Firstname','Company','Title','Willing_to_share','Willing_to_introduce','work_phones','Work_email','Work_Street','Work_City','Work_State','Work_Zip','Personal_Street','Personal_City','Personal_State','Personal_Zip','mobile_phones','Personal_email','Note','Note_Category']]

row = 2
column = 0

if (df['Lastname'] != ' ' & df['Firstname'] != ' ') & ((df['Company'] != ' ' & df['Title'] != ' ') | (df['Company'] == ' ') & (df['work_phones'] != ' ') | (df['mobile_phones'] != ' ') & (df['Personal_Street'] != ' ' & df['Personal_City'] != ' ' & df['Personal_State'] != ' ' & df['Personal_Zip'] != ' ') | (df['Work_Street'] != ' ' & df['Work_City'] != ' ' & df['Work_State'] != ' ' & df['Work_Zip'] != ' ' & (df['Work_email'] != ' ' | df['Personal_email'] != ' '))):


    row += 1
    worksheet.write(row, column, df)

else:

    row += 1  
    worksheet2.write(row, column, df)
```

I expect the rows that pass the if statement to be inserted starting in the third row of the first xlsx worksheet. Otherwise, the rows that do not pass should be inserted starting in the third row of the second xlsx worksheet. I am currently getting an TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: Please, add the full traceback of your error. Is what you posted your real code or just a guideline? If not, post your real code please.

Comment: And include all `import` lines and assignment of all objects so code is compilable and runnable in empty Python environment (i.e., [mcve]).

Comment: Thank you Valentino and Parfait. This is the real code and I added the import lines and the origin of the data set which is a csv file then converted into a pandas data set

Comment: Please properly format your code. The code above won't run as there's no tabs/indentations after while loop & where does it end?

Comment: Is the .loc considered a for loop or a while loop? Does it require an indentation like a regular for, while loop or an if statement?

Comment: The table headers are on line 13 and followed by the row and column numbers to start on
The df.loc statement is on line 18 and extends until the end of the code